# Issue in viewing site in browsers when using WP Super Cache along WP Mobilizer

Tags: wordpress, caching

For one of my sites, i use WP Super Cache along with WP Mobilizer to serve the mobile theme for mobile/smartphone visitors.

What is happening, from time to time, the desktop version shows the mobile site and mobile site shows the desktop version.

This is frustrating when a mobile visitor is unable to see a mobile optimized theme.

For the record, W3 Total Cache does not work on my box and i switched over to Super Cache after my dedicated server crashed on a default install of total cache. Even before it could be configured, load spiked so much that the server kept running out of memory.

back to the issue, i posted a support ticket on both the plugins @wordpress, but not a single response. I emailed the authors offering to pay them for their time but still nothing.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Does the site work after removing the Super Cache plugin? I guess the issue is when a visitor on same IP visits your website from different devices the previous version of the site is loaded. I suggest not to use WP Super Cache as it is outdated and many problems are reported after updating WP, you should move to some other cache plugin like http://wordpress.org/plugins/quick-cache/

Comment: No, actually i have never removed Super Cache and tried it. The issue happens even on different ips. I use my ISP for desktop and my mobile carrier for the smartphone. So, 2 different ips. I will take a look at quick cache. Thank you.

Comment: As a matter of fact, i had seen quick cache before and installed it. But Super Cache gives me a better performance and page speed numbers than quick cache.